# How to set a part of arguments from a list in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: list, emacs, lisp, elisp

I want to set `PROGRAM-ARGS` of `start-process` from a list.

Like,

```
(start-process process-name "*foobar*" process-path (append some-args (list (concat "the" "other" "arg"))))
```

But this makes error that "... is not string", because start-process accepts only string arguments.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please include the full error copied and pasted as-is.

Comment: What's so hard about showing the _real_ arguments to `start-process`, instead of `foobar` and `some-args` and `"the" "other" "arg"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want either `apply` or sometimes `funcall`.  In this particular case I would go with `apply` but you need to be familiar with them both.

```
(apply #'start-process process-name "*foobar*" process-path
       some-args other-args-as-a-list)
```