# How can I map an unknown list of args to start-process in elisp?

Tags: elisp

I'm finally trying to learn elisp but haven't wrapped my head around how to map an unknown list of arguments to variables dynamically.

Here's a working function that passes up to three arguments to start-process.  But I would like to pass an infinite number of args to the function.

```
(defun create-drush-buffer (command &rest a)
  (if (locate-dominating-file default-directory "includes/bootstrap.inc")
      (progn
        (setq opt1 (car a))
        (setq opt2 (cadr a))
        (setq opt3 (caddr a))
        (setq allopt (concat opt1 " " opt2 " " opt3))
        (setq b-name (concat "*drush " command " " allopt "*"))
        (if (buffer-live-p b-name)
            (switch-to-buffer b-name)
          (setq d-buffer (get-buffer-create  b-name))
          (with-current-buffer d-buffer
            (goto-char (point-min))
            (view-mode 1)
            (hl-line-mode 1)
            (if opt3
                (start-process "drush" (current-buffer) drupal-drush-program
                               command
                               opt1
                               opt2
                               opt3)
              (if opt2
                  (start-process "drush" (current-buffer)
                                 drupal-drush-program
                                 command
                                 opt1
                                 opt2)
                (if opt1
                    (start-process "drush" (current-buffer)
                                   drupal-drush-program
                                   command
                                   opt1)
                  (start-process "drush" (current-buffer)
                                 drupal-drush-program
                                 command))))
            (shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer))
          (switch-to-buffer d-buffer)))
    (message (concat default-directory " is not a drupal project"))))
```

Here's an example of a calling function I would like to work with create-drush-buffer.

```
(defun drush-sql-sync ()
  (interactive)
  (create-drush-buffer
   "sql-sync"
   "-y"
   "-d"
   "-v"
   "@cu.wstage1-education"
  "@cu.local-education"))
```

How can I achieve this and make my code less redundant?  Any help with code or even steering me to relevant documentation appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a part of arguments from a list in Emacs Lisp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411152/how-to-set-a-part-of-arguments-from-a-list-in-emacs-lisp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

> (apply FUNCTION &rest ARGUMENTS)
>
> Call FUNCTION with our remaining args, using our last arg as list of
>   args. Then return the value FUNCTION returns. Thus, (apply '+ 1 2 '(3
>   4)) returns 10.

This way, you could call `start-process` using something like:

```
(apply 'start-process "drush" (current-buffer)
                             drupal-drush-program
                             command
                             a)
```

As a side note, you should not create temporary variables using `setq`, as this creates or modified global variables (if no local ones with the name exists). Instead, use `let`.

Good luck with your elisp projects!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Glad I asked here as I might not have stumbled upon this solution for some time.